# Compass on top left of the map using Google maps api V3 in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

How to insert the compass button on the top left of the Google map. I am now working on phonegap using the Google maps api V3, except compass everything is fine. I should not use plugins for android, I need the compass button on the map. Thanks in advance.